# How to get code coverage data from Rust integration tests

Tags: testing, rust, integration-testing, code-coverage, test-coverage

I am currently contributing to a Rust open source project. The project uses the standard Rust unit tests for some of its testing. However, it does most of its testing by using Bats integration tests. The Bats tests just run the binary. Is it possible to get code coverage data from the integration tests somehow?

I have tried using `kcov` but as far as I can tell, it isn't getting the code coverage, it's just determining what lines of the tests were being run, which is not at all what I need.

Comment: Using the [instrumentation-based code coverage](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rustc/instrument-coverage.html) should produce coverage info regardless of how the binary is run. Or you can modify Bats to run with kcov (I'm not familiar with Bats so idk how hard that would be). Or you can convert the tests to rust, but that's probably not gonna go over well.

Comment: use tarpaulin https://github.com/xd009642/tarpaulin